# Strange behavior for a wordpress website hosted on IIS 10

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I have an wordpress (version 6.0.1) website hosted on IIS 10 with PHP (version PHP 7.4.30), that works intermittently (sometimes it does work other times it's not the page I'm looking for but the page served by DNS server). The DNS I'm using is https://freedns.afraid.org/.

On the same IIS server I have another asp app, with domain.

How I can fix this, the browser console doesn't return any error.

I tried with default wordpress theme and it does the same thing.

In php.ini I have this configuration :

```
post_max_size = 0
upload_max_filesize = 4096M
memory_limit = 4096M
```

In wp-config.php I added this line :

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT',  '512M');
```

Even after I changed these settings, still the same issue.

Comment: Check the WP_Memory_limit

Comment: "sometimes it does work other times it's not the page I'm looking for but the page served by DNS server" Please show some screen shots for such difficult to understand descriptions.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot your problem without an error message, and no error message in the console when it doesn't work?

Comment: @samwu yep, no error message in console when it doesn't work.

Comment: @LexLi this is the page served by DNS page : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBoAm.png

Comment: @HowardE I did try that, still same issue.

Comment: Not sure why you preferred such a strange DNS service, but you can reach out to its support channel and see if anyone can reply to you https://freedns.afraid.org/contact/ That page is clearly an advertisement to promote this service. Keep in mind that nothing is totally free.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with a WordPress website hosted in IIS server and using XAMPP for the data base (MySQL). I am using same DNS. The page tested on more than one PC seems to not load and is showing of this image . [Error image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBoAm.png)

Sometimes it does work other times it's not, for example it can work on chrome but not on edge and some time later work on edge but not on chrome. It can also work on all browsers same time or don't work at all on any browsers. Browser console returns this error:

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

The error image seems to show randomly.